# Deallocate javascript on uiwebview?

Tags: javascript, iphone, memory, uiwebview

is there way to deallocate the javascript after used in uiwebview.
what i understand was the iOS will execute the app when javascript didn't finished within 10 s and when memory get 10 MB limit.
Can we control this two by ourself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no document given by apple to deallocate javascript on UIWebView but one thing you can do by handling `appDelegate` method `- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application`.

In this method release the unwanted resources and stop loading data on webview:

```
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
                  [webView stopLoading];
                  [webView setDelegate:nil];
                 //As per the requirement do your stuff here (like release unwanted objects)
}
```